# Corrupted data.frame contains lists - how to convert to columns?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a `data.frame`, called "so_data".

Columns 13:23 are `list`s, which hold empty cells and single values. How do I convert them to numeric vectors?

I have tried:

```
matrix(unlist(rang[13:23]), ncol=11, byrow=F)
```

But apparently I loose all empty cells. Which messes everything up.

```
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, rang)))
```

Essentially doesn't change the data.

Here's the data:

```
so_data <- structure(list(id = c(83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 104L, 105L
), motivation..1. = structure(c(7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("", 
"Kald", "Udviklingspotentiale", "Alsidigt arbejdsliv", "Noget jeg kan lide", 
"egen", "godti", "indko", "inter", "jobsi", "samfn", "statu"), class = "factor"), 
    motivation..2. = structure(c(5L, 11L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 
    4L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("", 
    "Kald", "Udviklingspotentiale", "Alsidigt arbejdsliv", "Noget jeg kan lide", 
    "egen", "godti", "indko", "inter", "jobsi", "samfn", "statu"
    ), class = "factor"), motivation..3. = structure(c(4L, 9L, 
    11L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 
    9L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("", "Kald", "Udviklingspotentiale", 
    "Alsidigt arbejdsliv", "Noget jeg kan lide", "egen", "godti", 
    "indko", "inter", "jobsi", "samfn", "statu"), class = "factor"), 
    motivation..4. = structure(c(11L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 
    11L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 8L), .Label = c("", 
    "Kald", "Udviklingspotentiale", "Alsidigt arbejdsliv", "Noget jeg kan lide", 
    "egen", "godti", "indko", "inter", "jobsi", "samfn", "statu"
    ), class = "factor"), motivation..5. = structure(c(3L, 7L, 
    10L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 7L, 6L, 10L), .Label = c("", "Kald", "Udviklingspotentiale", 
    "Alsidigt arbejdsliv", "Noget jeg kan lide", "egen", "godti", 
    "indko", "inter", "jobsi", "samfn", "statu"), class = "factor"), 
    motivation..6. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), motivation..7. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), motivation..8. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    motivation..9. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), motivation..10. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), motivation..11. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), godti = structure(list(`3` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), 
        `4` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `5` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `6` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `8` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `9` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `10` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `11` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `12` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), 
        `13` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `14` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `15` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `17` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `18` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `19` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `20` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `21` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `22` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), 
        `24` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `25` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2.")), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), Udviklingspotentiale = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `4` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), 
        `5` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `6` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), 
        `8` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `9` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `10` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `11` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), 
        `12` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `13` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `14` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `15` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `17` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `18` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `19` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `20` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), 
        `21` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), `22` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `24` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `25` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3.")), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), `Noget jeg kan lide` = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `4` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `5` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `6` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), 
        `8` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `9` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), 
        `10` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `11` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), 
        `12` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `13` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), 
        `14` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `15` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), 
        `17` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `18` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), 
        `19` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), `20` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), 
        `21` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `22` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `24` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `25` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1.")), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), jobsi = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `4` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `5` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `6` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `8` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `9` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), 
        `10` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `11` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `12` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `13` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), `14` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `15` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `17` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `18` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `19` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `20` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), 
        `21` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `22` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `24` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `25` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5.")), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), Kald = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `4` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `5` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), `6` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `8` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `9` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `10` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `11` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `12` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), `13` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `14` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `15` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), 
        `17` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `18` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `19` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `20` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `21` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `22` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `24` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `25` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0))), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), statu = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `4` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `5` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `6` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `8` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `9` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `10` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `11` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `12` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `13` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `14` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `15` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `17` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `18` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `19` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `20` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `21` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `22` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `24` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `25` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0))), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), indko = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `4` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `5` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `6` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `8` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `9` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `10` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), `11` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `12` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `13` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `14` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `15` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `17` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `18` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `19` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `20` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), 
        `21` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `22` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `24` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `25` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4.")), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), inter = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `4` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), 
        `5` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `6` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `8` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), `9` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), 
        `10` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `11` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `12` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `13` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), 
        `14` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `15` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `17` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `18` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `19` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `20` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), `21` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), 
        `22` = structure(2L, .Names = "motivation..1."), `24` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `25` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0))), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), `Alsidigt arbejdsliv` = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `4` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `5` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `6` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), 
        `8` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `9` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `10` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `11` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), 
        `12` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `13` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), 
        `14` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `15` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `17` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `18` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `19` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `20` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `21` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `22` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `24` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `25` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0))), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), samfn = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), `4` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), 
        `5` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), `6` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `8` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `9` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `10` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `11` = structure(5L, .Names = "motivation..4."), 
        `12` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `13` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `14` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `15` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `17` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `18` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), `19` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `20` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `21` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `22` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `24` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `25` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0))), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25")), egen = structure(list(
        `3` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `4` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `5` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `6` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `8` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), `9` = structure(4L, .Names = "motivation..3."), 
        `10` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `11` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `12` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `13` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `14` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `15` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `17` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `18` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `19` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `20` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `21` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), 
        `22` = structure(3L, .Names = "motivation..2."), `24` = structure(6L, .Names = "motivation..5."), 
        `25` = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0))), .Names = c("3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "24", "25"))), .Names = c("id", 
"motivation..1.", "motivation..2.", "motivation..3.", "motivation..4.", 
"motivation..5.", "motivation..6.", "motivation..7.", "motivation..8.", 
"motivation..9.", "motivation..10.", "motivation..11.", "godti", 
"Udviklingspotentiale", "Noget jeg kan lide", "jobsi", "Kald", 
"statu", "indko", "inter", "Alsidigt arbejdsliv", "samfn", "egen"
), row.names = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

**Edit:** *What created this mess?*

The `data.frame` above started with 12 columns, `id` and eleven factors. These are `so_data[1:12]`.

The eleven factors are produced by a ranking question in a survey. Something like *"For each of the following 11 reasons to choose a university, please rank the five reasons, most important to you".*

Each of the eleven columns then represents a choice. Since only five choices where allowed, only the five first columns (`so_data[2:6]`) holds relevant data.

Now - for me to do some calculations and plotting, I needed to transform the data a bit. Instead of having 5 columns that represented "priority no. 1", "priority no. 2" etc, I wanted 11 columns each representing a reason. Each column then has values according to what priority the respondent assigned to that reason.

e.g.,

Instead of:

```
-------------|Priority 1------- | Priority 2---| ... | Priority 5 |
respondent1  | raeason X        | Reason Y     | ... | reason z    | 
...
```

I want:

```
-------------| Reason 1 -------  | Reason 2    ---| ... | Reason 11 |
respondent1  | Priority z        | Priority 2     | ... | Priority 5
...
```

This is the code that, a clever man help me with:

```
startcolidx = 2
endcolidx = 6
factors = unique(unlist(rang[,startcolidx:endcolidx]))


for(f in as.character(factors)) {
   rang[[f]] = apply(rang, 1, function(arow) which(arow == f))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data.frame is apparently corrupted: some of the columns are lists of 1- or 0-element vectors -- this is not supposed to happen, in a data.frame.
Rather than trying to fix it, it is probably wiser, and easier, to fix the code that generated it.

If you insisted on fixing the data rather than the underlying problem, the following may work:

```
do.call(data.frame, 
  lapply( so_data, 
    function (u) unlist( 
      if( is.list(u) ) lapply(u, function(v) c(v,NA)[1]) 
      else u 
)))
```

**Edit:** You can transform your initial data with `melt` and `dcast`.

```
library(reshape2)
d <- so_data[1:6]

# Transform the data to a tall format:
# it is much easier to process data in tall format.
d <- melt(d, id.vars="id" )

# Transfrom the data to a wide format: 
# just specify the rows and the columns on each side of ~.
# It is rarely necessary to specify value.var.
d <- dcast( d, id ~ value, value.var="variable" )
```

Comment: Thanx - I'll try your fix, but I'll also update the code that generated the dataframe.

Comment: The fix worked :-D

I don't really understand your code ... It checks if each elements datatype. If a list is found, you insert a "NA", and unlist it?

Comment: For each column of the data.frame, I check if it is a list. If so, let us call it u. I then take each element v of this list: it is a vector of length 0 or 1, that I want to transform into a vector of length 1 (containing NA, if there was no data). To do so, I consider the vector `c(v,NA)`, which contains 1 or 2 elements, and take its first element. To write that code, I work backwards: I first try to see what I can do to fix v, then to fix u, and finally to fix the whole data.frame. But even if I can write that kind of code, I cannot really read it either...

Comment: @Andreas: I have updated my answer to show how to produce a correct data.frame in the first place.